# AngularJS matching data between json arrays and setting a selected option

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

```
$scope.opts =
        {
        unit: [
            { id: 1, val: "px", name: "px"},
            { id: 2, val: "%", name: "%"}
        ]
}
```

The above is my options list array and now I set my default option.

```
$scope.user.unit = $scope.opts.unit[0];
```

The above creates the following in my `html`

```
<select class="unit ng-pristine ng-valid" data-ng-options="a.name for a in opts.unit" data-ng-model="user.unit">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">px</option>
    <option value="1">%</option>
</select>
```

When I use the below I am pulling the data that was stored in a db from the options selected in the above example.

```
$http.get('/assets/inc/file.php?id='+thisPage).success(function(response) {
    var userData = response.userData;
    var locationData = response.locationData;
    $scope.user = userData;
    $scope.locations = locationData;
    console.log($scope.user.unit);
});
```

This console.logs me the following `Object { id=1, val="px", name="px"}`

I may be wrong but the `<select>` box is binded to `$scope.opts`

How would I be able to link the retrieved data from `$scope.user.unit` to `$scope.opts.unit` so that when the data is retrieved it will then mark the correct option as `:selected`?

Comment: That should be updating it...mind creating a Plunkr?

Comment: There's a much easier way to do this than manually going through the arrays. It involves how you set your ng-options and the your ng-model on the select.   I can post this in about 2 hrs when I'm back in front of a computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.opts ={
    unit: [
        { id: 1, val: "px", name: "px"},
        { id: 2, val: "%", name: "%"},
        { id: 3, val: "pt", name: "pt"}
    ]
}
```

I noticed that the $scope.opts builds my `select` element and populates it but when the data is retrieved via db it needs to go into `$scope.user.unit` but this is binded to `$scope.opts` so what I have done is sought out the `ID` for the item that was retrieved and then added `-1` to it so it will select from the array of `$scope.opts.unit`

`var testUnit = $scope.user.unit.id-1; //gets the ID of the unit thats been retrieved`

`$scope.user.unit = $scope.opts.unit[testUnit]; //sets the selected option in the dom`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but you can try this (or create JSFiddle): 
JS:

```
$http.get('/assets/inc/file.php?id='+thisPage).success(function(response) {
    var userData = response.userData;
    var locationData = response.locationData;
    $scope.user = userData;
    $scope.locations = locationData;
    $scope.selected = {};
    angular.forEach($scope.opts.unit, function (value)
            {
                if (value.val == $scope.user.unit.val) {

                    $scope.selected = value
                }

            });
    console.log($scope.user.unit);
});
```

and in View:

```
 <select class="unit ng-pristine ng-valid" data-ng-options="a.name for a in opts.unit" data-ng-model="user.unit">
<option value="{{selected.val}}">{{selected.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ng-model for the select element is an object, and not a primitive type, which is fine, but then you reassign $scope.user to a brand new object (returned from $http.get), so user.unit is a new object too, so it's not identical to any of your ng-options. I can think of two ways which should fix the problem:

1. bind the select to the 'id' property of the unit object:

   ```
   <select ng-options="a.id as a.name for a in opts.unit" ng-model="user.unit.id">
   ```
2. or leave the select bound to user.unit, but use the track by feature of ng-options:

   ```
   <select ng-options="a.name for a in opts.unit track by a.id" ng-model="user.unit">
   ```

Answer (score 0):

One of the things in Angular is that you rarely need to do is explicitly create `<option>` elements manually as the framework will generate this for you.  Therefore, the following will work: (Working jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/LMHLq/12/)

HTML:

```
<select data-ng-model='user.unit' data-ng-options="o.id as o.name for o in opts.unit"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.opts ={
    unit: [
        { id: 1, val: "px", name: "px"},
        { id: 2, val: "%", name: "%"},
        { id: 3, val: "pt", name: "pt"}
    ]
}

$http.get('/assets/inc/file.php?id='+thisPage).success(function(response) {

    var userData = response.userData;
    var locationData = response.locationData;
    $scope.user = userData;
    $scope.locations = locationData;
    console.log($scope.user.unit);
});
```